Bringing array values ​containing map in firestore using Swift
I'm developing an app for my school project and I stuck in an issue and I'm not able to handle it. I’m trying to get midTerm, finalTerm and lectureGradeId values from my Firebase Cloud Firestore. Except that values, I'm able to get every value from Firestore.
To make it clear, I'm putting my codes and my Firestore structure below:
Students.swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Grades: Codable, Hashable {
var lectureGradeId: String
var midTerm: String
var endTerm: String
}

struct Students: Identifiable, Codable {
var id: String
var email: String
var studentName: String
var studentSurname: String
var studentTerm: String
var studentBirthday: String
var studentClass: Int
var studentDept: String
var studentFaculty: String
var studentIsActive: Bool
var studentIsGraduated: Bool
var studentLectures: [String]?
var studentGrades: [Grades]?
}

StudentsViewModel.swift
import Foundation
import Firebase

class StudentsViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var students = [Students]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData() {
    db.collection("Students").whereField("id", isEqualTo: "20704029").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.students = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Students in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
            let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentName = data["studentName"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentSurname = data["studentSurname"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentTerm = data["studentTerm"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentBirthday = data["studentBirthday"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentClass = data["studentClass"] as? Int ?? 0
            let studentDept = data["studentDept"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentFaculty = data["studentFaculty"] as? String ?? ""
            let studentIsActive = data["studentIsActive"] as? Bool ?? true
            let studentIsGraduated = data["studentIsGraduated"] as? Bool ?? false
            let studentLectures = data["studentLectures"] as? Array ?? [""]
            
            let student = Students(id: id, email: email, studentName: studentName, studentSurname: studentSurname, studentTerm: studentTerm, studentBirthday: studentBirthday, studentClass: studentClass, studentDept: studentDept, studentFaculty: studentFaculty, studentIsActive: studentIsActive, studentIsGraduated: studentIsGraduated, studentLectures: studentLectures)
            //print(student)
            return student
        }
    }
}
}

GradesPage.swift
import SwiftUI

struct GradesPage: View {

@ObservedObject private var viewModel = StudentsViewModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.students) { student in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Student Name: ") + Text(" ") + Text(student.studentName) + Text(" ") + Text(student.studentSurname)
                //I want to add the grades to see in here but don't know how to handle it
            }
        }
    }.onAppear {
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
    }
}
}

Firestore Structure:

Solutions that I tried:
Peter Friese Documentation
Firestore Official Documentation
Thanks in advance, all helps are welcome!

Note, you should be using
@StateObject private var viewModel = StudentsViewModel().
Also note, there is no finalTerm in your code
and NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack
To display studentGrades in your GradesPage View,
simply use a ForEach, such as:
struct GradesPage: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = StudentsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <--- here
            List(viewModel.students) { student in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Student Name: ") + Text(" ") + Text(student.studentName) + Text(" ") + Text(student.studentSurname)

                    ForEach(student.studentGrades ?? []) { grade in  // <--- here
                       Text(grade.lectureGradeId)
                       Text(grade.midTerm)
                       Text(grade.endTerm)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

struct Grades: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {  //<--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var lectureGradeId: String
    var midTerm: String
    var endTerm: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lectureGradeId, midTerm, endTerm
    }
}

struct Students: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var email: String
    var studentName: String
    var studentSurname: String
    var studentTerm: String
    var studentBirthday: String
    var studentClass: Int
    var studentDept: String
    var studentFaculty: String
    var studentIsActive: Bool
    var studentIsGraduated: Bool
    var studentLectures: [String]?
    var studentGrades: [Grades]?
}


class StudentsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var students = [Students]()

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("Students").whereField("id", isEqualTo: "20704029").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.students = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Students in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentName = data["studentName"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentSurname = data["studentSurname"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentTerm = data["studentTerm"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentBirthday = data["studentBirthday"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentClass = data["studentClass"] as? Int ?? 0
                let studentDept = data["studentDept"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentFaculty = data["studentFaculty"] as? String ?? ""
                let studentIsActive = data["studentIsActive"] as? Bool ?? true
                let studentIsGraduated = data["studentIsGraduated"] as? Bool ?? false
                let studentLectures = data["studentLectures"] as? Array ?? [""]
                
                // <--- something like this, adjust as needed, don't remember how it works
                let studentGrades = data["studentGrades"] as? [Grades] ?? []

                let student = Students(id: id, email: email, studentName: studentName, studentSurname: studentSurname, studentTerm: studentTerm, studentBirthday: studentBirthday, studentClass: studentClass, studentDept: studentDept, studentFaculty: studentFaculty, studentIsActive: studentIsActive, studentIsGraduated: studentIsGraduated, studentLectures: studentLectures,
                    studentGrades: studentGrades   //<--- here
                )

                //print(student)
                return student
            }
        }
    }
}

Note, you could try mapping the results of the firebase query directly into
your codable Students struct, see for example:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping  and  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
For example, from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping
func fetchData() {
    let docRef = db.collection("Students").whereField("id", isEqualTo: "20704029")
    docRef.getDocument(as: Students.self) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let students):
            self.students = students
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error decoding document: \(error)")
            // todo deal with errors
        }
    }
}
 


Thanks for your answer but there are some problems. The first thing is; I wrote down everything and nothing changed. I can't still get the values. And the second thing; at the second code snippet, I get error at docRef.getDocument(as: Students.self) { result in which says "Value of type 'Query' has no member 'getDocument' ", so I can't use it. Can you enlighten me?

Ok, since I don't have your database, I cannot try the code, however you could try using something like let docRef = db.collection("Students").document("20704029"). If need be, try using @DocumentID var id: String? in your struct Students
as the docs in the link indicates.

After making many researchs, I finally solved my problem. First, I tried every code in the answer of @workingdog support Ukraine. But I failed at the second code snippet, normally getDocument method is using for a single document but I'm using many documents in my code. So, I changed my code like this:
let query = db.collection("Students").whereField("id", isEqualTo: "20704029")
query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
if let error = error {
    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
    // todo deal with errors
} else {
    self.students = snapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
        try? document.data(as: Students.self)
} ?? []
}
}

After the changes, my app started to work as I desired and here's a screenshot about it:

Now my problem is solved.
